# No me logea la APK compilada con SIGN IN, pero con dispositivos virtuales si (con GoogleSignInClient)

Tags: kotlin

Buenas desarrole una App en kotlin en android studio, y la voy probando con los dispositivos dispositivos virtuales que ofrece android studio y anda todo bien mi APP. Se logea correctamente utilizando el ejemplo siguiente ( https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in?hl=es-419 ). Sale el POPUP y no me tira ningun error, pero si genero la APK (la compilo) y la pruebo en mi cel. No me funciona, perooo si pongo mi celular como dispositivo fisico para probar usando android studio me anda lo mas bien.
Ejemplo: Linkeo mi celular por medio de USB a android studio y pongo RUN, la aplicacion anda lo mas bien y no me tira error, pero si compilo la aplicacion en APK y lo paso al celular que ya probe que anda, me tira erro (resultCode = 0) cuando quiero logearme con el mail de google
Que puede ser ?d (NO  uso FIREBASE, solo configure como esta en el ejemplo google cloud, google drive api)